# No word morphology in NLTK FUF?

Tags: nltk

I'm trying to output the simple sentence "The man eats the meal." using the NLTK FUF linearize() function [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/fuf/linearizer.py)

All I do is pass a unified input/grammar to linearize(). But when I do that I get the output "The man eat the meal". I took a look at the [morphology.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/fuf/morphology.py) module and it seems to have all the appropriate functions to morphologize sentences. The default tense for verbs in FUF is the present tense, so "eat" should be converted to "eats".

I did notice, however, that linearizer.py isn't using any of the functions in morphology.py and I'm thinking that perhaps that is why nothing is being morphologized. I tried adding [number = 'plural'] to the feature structure for the direct object in the input sentence so that it would output "The man eats the meals", but that doesn't work either. I have a feeling that the linearizer.py module is incomplete, but first I want to rule out that I'm not doing anything wrong. You can try the test for yourself at the bottom of the linearizer.py [module](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/fuf/linearizer.py) 
Please let me know what result you get and please advise.

thanks

Mika